# Diff of files that have been added but not committed using GIT?

Tags: git, diff

I have added a bunch of files using the following command:

```
git add .
```

But before I commit the changes, I would first like to review the changes again using diff.

What is the command to achieve this?

Comment: You can also review changes as you add them by using `git add -p`.

Comment: `git diff --staged` (from the other question) seems to do exactly what I need. I am surprised that my search didn't find the existing question, sorry guys :-)